# Игнорируются поля в JSON строке

Tags: java, json, jackson

Поля `lon` и `lat` почему то игнорируются

```
public class Coord {

    private double lon;

    private double lat;

    public double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public void setLon(double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public Coord() {
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    Coord res = mapper.readValue(someString, Coord.class);

    System.out.println(res.getLat() + " " + res.getLon()); // 0.0 0.0 
}
```

`someString = {"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вашего класса `Coord` нет свойства `coord`, вот оно и игнорируется.

Вот так должно сработать (наверное):

```
someString = {"lon":-0.13, "lat":51.51}
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, действительно, спасибо. 
Вот так выглядит рабочий код если с моей строкой:

```
public class Response {
private coord coord;

public coord getCoord() {
    return coord;
}

public void setCoord(coord coord){
    this.coord = coord;
}

public Response () {};
class coord {
    private double lon;

    private double lat;

    coord (double lon, double lat) {
        this.lon = lon;
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public void setLon(double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }
    public coord() {
    }
}
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Response res = mapper.readValue(someString, Response.class);
System.out.println(res.getCoord().getLat() + " " + res.getCoord().getLon());

someString = {"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51}}
```